# Upstart and pre/post scripts

Tags: linux, upstart, init

I run into an issue with upstart where I want to update an init config, but just restarting the job doesn't apply the changes.

For example:

- I've got job `xyz` running
- I modify the `/etc/init/xyz.conf` to do something in `pre-stop`.
- The job gets restarted with `restart xyz`
- `pre-stop` part is not executed

I tried reloading the config with `initctl reload-configuration`, but it didn't have any effect. If I manually stop and start the job in two separate steps, things work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas), the [pre-stop](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#pre-stop) stanza is only executed before a stop command, not during a (warm) restart.

```
Description: Command executed when a job in running state gets stopped (initctl stop or stop on event).
```

Depending on what you are trying to do you may not be able to avoid this behavior.